# What is the definition of a aperiodic Markov chain?

Tags: markov-process, definition

I understand the definition of a state being aperiodic or periodic with period d. But what does it mean for a chain to be aperiodic / periodic with period d?

Thanks.

Comment: _Aperiodic_ imples $d = 1,$ so 'aperiodic of period $d$' would be redundant, and make one wonder if 'periodic of period $d$' was intended.

Comment: Yes, I never wrote 'aperiodic of period d', did I?

Comment: You wrote that you understand "the definition of a state being aperiodic or periodic with period d" and then asked (ambiguously?) "what does it mean for a chain to be aperiodic / periodic with period d? " Just trying to focus on what you're asking.

Comment: I understood periodicity for states but not for chains.

Comment: If the chain is irreducible (just one intercommunicating class) then all states in the chain have the same period.

Comment: @BruceET (aperiodic)/(periodic with period d). The sentence is not really ambiguous for exactly the reason you described: *aperiodic of period d* would be redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A state $s$ is *aperiodic* if the times of possible (positive probability) return to $s$ have a largest common denominator equal to one. A *chain* is *aperiodic* if it is irreducible and if all states are aperiodic, which is ensured by *one* state being aperiodic.

Comment: Thanks. What if a state in the chain is periodic? Will all the other states have the same period? If not, what do we say about the period of the chain?

Comment: See my edit: if the chain is irreducible, all states have the same period.

Comment: Is irreducibility necessary for an aperiodic Markov chain? Could we have an aperiodic Markov chain with multiple communication classes where the diagonal of the transition matrix is strictly positive?

Comment: For a non-irreducible chain, each communicating class has its own properties. One may be periodic while another one is not, the period of one may differ from the period of another, &tc. Hence it makes little sense to consider an *aperiodic* non-irreducible Markov chain.